# Terrible Wifi performance once proprietary nvidia drivers installed

Tags: wireless, nvidia, iwlwifi

- Wifi card: Intel ax200
- GFx card: 2080
- Ubuntu Version: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
- Kernel: 5.8.5-050805-generic (latest mainline)

My wifi pings are perfect after installation. All 1-2ms. After I install the nvidia drivers and reboot ping times keep ascending until they're in the seconds and my wifi has completely died.

I've tried turning off power saving. Installed latest nvidia drivers. Installed latest kernel. Nothing works unless I remove the nvidia drivers and go back to open source. Open source however is broken with my monitor set up so that's not a good solution.

I don't understand why the gfx drivers would affect wifi performance like this.

No problems in Windows.

Comment: Please post the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s backport-iwlwifi-dkms | grep Status` and also: `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Not installed. 

I actually solved my problem by installing an older version of the AX200 driver into /lib/firmware

Answer (score 0):

I neglected to mention the AX200 I have is in an ASUS PCE-AX3000.

As a last ditch effort I went to to the support page and downloaded the drivers from ASUS. They're obviously older than the current drivers.

Moving the ucode files into /lib/firmware has fixed the issue.